# Offline creation of signed contract transactions with web3js v1.2.11

Tags: web3js, transactions, signature, web3js-v1.x, offline

I'm attempting to sign a contract transaction offline using web3js v1.2.11.

```
signingAddr = //my eth address
signingPk = //my private key

// docs: The options object for the contract instance. from, gas and gasPrice are used as fallback values when sending transactions.
myContractInstance.options = {
  gas : 800000,
  gasPrice : 60000000000,
  value : 1000000000000000,
  from : signingAddr
}
//docs: Creates a transaction object for that method, which then can be called, send, estimated.
let tx = await myContractInstance.methods.myFunction(myParam1,myParam2)

//docs: "Signs an Ethereum transaction with a given private key."
let signedTx = await web3.eth.signTransaction(tx,signingPk)

console.log(signedtx)
//Error: The send transactions "from" field must be defined!
```

I've also tried with:

```
let tx = await myContractInstance.methods.myFunction(myParam1,myParam2).send({from:signingAddr})
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Links to docs:

- [contract options](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html#options)
- [contract method call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)
- [signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction)

I get that the tx object returned by the contract method is different to the tx object required for `signTransaction`. I'm unsure as to whether this is possible with web3.js?

It [seems](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12932/820) in earlier versions of web3js there was a `getData` function to get the needed call data.

**How can I create valid signed contract call transactions offline using webjs v1.2.11?**

Comment: https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/52784/820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tx object is the following :

```
const tx = {
  nonce: nonce,
  gasPrice: gasPrice,
  gasLimit: gasLimit,
  to: contractAddress,
  value: value,
  data: contractData,
};
```

I think what you are looking for is the data parameter which is obtained using the `enoceABI()` web3 function (cf https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi):

```
contractData = myContractInstance.methods.myFunction(myParam1,myParam2).encodeABI();
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! Now battling with `unknown account` error - perhaps I also have to initialise a wallet.

Comment: Yes, you need a valid pair of public/private keys.

Comment: Yes I have that, I get error on `web3.eth.signTransaction(tx,<my_valid_Pk>)`

Comment: Perhaps the public address has to be added to `web3.accounts` object somehow, is what I meant.

Comment: Maybe related to this : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38146/web3-eth-sendtransaction-unknown-account-error .

Answer (score 2):

I had a number of things wrong:

To add to @clement's answer, `tx` should be:

```
  tx = {
    nonce: nonce,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
    to: contractAddress,
    value: value,
    data: contractData,
    chainId : 1,
}); //add chainId
```

I also needed to create an account object:

```
let acc = await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signingPrivateKey)
```

And then call `signTransaction` on that:

```
signedtx = await acc.signTransaction(tx,signingPrivateKey)
```